# Strange SSL error when seeding database via command line

Tags: python, ssl, amazon-dynamodb

I have a file (it's called conversation_template.py) which I use to seed my DynamoDB database, and it worked until very recently.

```
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')
table = dynamodb.Table('tablename')

data = {'<data_goes_here>'}


def add_to_table():
        table.put_item(Item=data)


add_to_table()
```

Now, when I run it in my command line, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 279, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 401, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 808, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1061, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 683, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:748)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 574, in urlopen
    raise SSLError(e)
botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:748)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conversation_template.py", line 74, in <module>
    add_to_table()
  File "conversation_template.py", line 71, in add_to_table
    table.put_item(Item=episode)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 83, in __call__
    response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 312, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 588, in _make_api_call
    operation_model, request_dict)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 141, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 170, in _send_request
    success_response, exception):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 249, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception, request_dict=request_dict)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 227, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 210, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 251, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 277, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 317, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 223, in __call__
    attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 359, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 204, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/envs/django_pocketcoach/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:748)
```

I tried to figure out where the error comes from but I couldn’t do it. Even the error messages didn’t get me anywhere.

I get an SSLError; the protocol is unknown. I found that this type of error could be related to me trying to connect to proxy servers but I am not using one and haven’t done so in the past either.

Any ideas on where this error could come from?

Comment: This is just a stacktrace.. where's the code?

Comment: The code hasn't changed since it stopped working, so I'm sure it's not the issue. I'll add the code anyway

Answer (score 0):

What's worked in the end is to exit my current virtual environment and run:

```
/Applications/Python\ 3.6/Install\ Certificates.command
```

And then I entered my virtual environment again and ran:

```
pip install certifi
```

That fixed it.

I got help from a friend who suspected it could have to do with the certification verification (related to this: [urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) ) but it remains unclear why I didn't get a "Certificate Verification Failed" error.